# kafka streams do not run with dynamically generated classes

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to start a stream that deserialize a dynamically created Class. This Bean is created by use of reflection and URLCLassLOader with a given String Class as parameter, but the KafkaStreams API doesn't recognize my new class.

The streams work perfectly with pre-created Beans, but close automatically when the dynamic one is used. The deserilizer was created with Jackson and works alone too.

Here is the class parser code

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static Class<?> getClassFromSource(String className, String sourceCode)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    /*
     * create an empty source file
     */
    File sourceFile = new File(com.google.common.io.Files.createTempDir(), className + ".java");

    sourceFile.deleteOnExit();

    /*
     * generate the source code, using the source filename as the class name write
     * the source code into the source file
     */
    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sourceFile)) {
        writer.write(sourceCode);
    }

    /*
     * compile the source file
     */
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

    File parentDirectory = null;

    try (StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null)) {

        parentDirectory = sourceFile.getParentFile();

        fileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Arrays.asList(parentDirectory));

        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager
                .getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(sourceFile));

        compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, compilationUnits).call();
    }

    /*
     * load the compiled class
     */
    try (StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null)) {

        parentDirectory = sourceFile.getParentFile();

        fileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Arrays.asList(parentDirectory));

        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager
                .getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(sourceFile));

        compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, compilationUnits).call();
    }

    /*
     * load the compiled class
     */
    try (URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { parentDirectory.toURI().toURL() })) {
        return (Class<?>) classLoader.loadClass(className);
    }
}
```

First i instantiate my Serdes that receive a Class as parameter

```
// dynamic generated class from a source class
Class clazz = getClassFromSource("DynamicClass", source);

// Serdes for created class that implements org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer
DynamicDeserializer deserializer = new DynamicDeserializer(clazz);
DynamicSerializer serializer = new DynamicSerializer();
Serde<?> encryptedSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(serializer, deserializer);
```

And then start the Stream topology that use this Serdes

```
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

KTable<String, Long> dynamicStream = builder
            .stream(topicName, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), encryptedSerde))
            .groupByKey()
            .count();

dynamicStream.to(outputTopicName, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));
```

Stream topology should execute normally, but always generates this error

```
2019-09-01 14:54:16 WARN  ConsumerConfig:355 - The configuration 'log4j.appender.stdout.Target' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2019-09-01 14:54:16 WARN  ConsumerConfig:355 - The configuration 'log4j.appender.stdout.layout' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2019-09-01 14:54:16 WARN  ConsumerConfig:355 - The configuration 'log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2019-09-01 14:54:16 WARN  ConsumerConfig:355 - The configuration 'stream.restart.application' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2019-09-01 14:54:16 WARN  ConsumerConfig:355 - The configuration 'aes.key.path' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2019-09-01 14:54:16 WARN  ConsumerConfig:355 - The configuration 'path.to.listening' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2019-09-01 14:54:16 WARN  ConsumerConfig:355 - The configuration 'log4j.appender.stdout' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2019-09-01 14:54:16 WARN  ConsumerConfig:355 - The configuration 'admin.retries' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2019-09-01 14:54:16 WARN  ConsumerConfig:355 - The configuration 'log4j.rootLogger' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2019-09-01 14:54:16 INFO  AppInfoParser:117 - Kafka version: 2.3.0
2019-09-01 14:54:16 INFO  AppInfoParser:118 - Kafka commitId: fc1aaa116b661c8a
2019-09-01 14:54:16 INFO  AppInfoParser:119 - Kafka startTimeMs: 1567360456724
2019-09-01 14:54:16 INFO  KafkaStreams:800 - stream-client [streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-15574162-7649-4c98-acd2-7a68ced01d72] Started Streams client
2019-09-01 14:54:16 INFO  StreamThread:740 - stream-thread [streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-15574162-7649-4c98-acd2-7a68ced01d72-StreamThread-1] Starting
2019-09-01 14:54:16 INFO  StreamThread:207 - stream-thread [streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-15574162-7649-4c98-acd2-7a68ced01d72-StreamThread-1] State transition from CREATED to RUNNING
2019-09-01 14:54:16 INFO  KafkaConsumer:1027 - [Consumer clientId=streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-15574162-7649-4c98-acd2-7a68ced01d72-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=streamingbean-test-20190901145412544] Subscribed to pattern: 'DynamicBean|streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000003-repartition'
2019-09-01 14:54:17 INFO  Metadata:266 - [Producer clientId=streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-15574162-7649-4c98-acd2-7a68ced01d72-StreamThread-1-producer] Cluster ID: tp7OBhwVRQqT2NpPlL55_Q
2019-09-01 14:54:17 INFO  Metadata:266 - [Consumer clientId=streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-15574162-7649-4c98-acd2-7a68ced01d72-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=streamingbean-test-20190901145412544] Cluster ID: tp7OBhwVRQqT2NpPlL55_Q
2019-09-01 14:54:17 INFO  AbstractCoordinator:728 - [Consumer clientId=streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-15574162-7649-4c98-acd2-7a68ced01d72-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=streamingbean-test-20190901145412544] Discovered group coordinator AcerDerick:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-09-01 14:54:17 INFO  ConsumerCoordinator:476 - [Consumer clientId=streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-15574162-7649-4c98-acd2-7a68ced01d72-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=streamingbean-test-20190901145412544] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
2019-09-01 14:54:17 INFO  StreamThread:207 - stream-thread [streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-15574162-7649-4c98-acd2-7a68ced01d72-StreamThread-1] State transition from RUNNING to PARTITIONS_REVOKED
2019-09-01 14:54:17 INFO  KafkaStreams:257 - stream-client [streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-15574162-7649-4c98-acd2-7a68ced01d72] State transition from RUNNING to REBALANCING
2019-09-01 14:54:17 INFO  KafkaConsumer:1068 - [Consumer clientId=streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-15574162-7649-4c98-acd2-7a68ced01d72-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
2019-09-01 14:54:17 INFO  StreamThread:324 - stream-thread [streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-15574162-7649-4c98-acd2-7a68ced01d72-StreamThread-1] partition revocation took 0 ms.
    suspended active tasks: []
    suspended standby tasks: []
2019-09-01 14:54:17 INFO  AbstractCoordinator:505 - [Consumer clientId=streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-15574162-7649-4c98-acd2-7a68ced01d72-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=streamingbean-test-20190901145412544] (Re-)joining group
2019-09-01 14:54:17 ERROR StreamsPartitionAssignor:354 - stream-thread [streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-15574162-7649-4c98-acd2-7a68ced01d72-StreamThread-1-consumer] DynamicClass is unknown yet during rebalance, please make sure they have been pre-created before starting the Streams application.
2019-09-01 14:54:17 INFO  AbstractCoordinator:469 - [Consumer clientId=streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-15574162-7649-4c98-acd2-7a68ced01d72-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=streamingbean-test-20190901145412544] Successfully joined group with generation 1
2019-09-01 14:54:17 INFO  ConsumerCoordinator:283 - [Consumer clientId=streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-15574162-7649-4c98-acd2-7a68ced01d72-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=streamingbean-test-20190901145412544] Setting newly assigned partitions: 
2019-09-01 14:54:17 INFO  StreamThread:1164 - stream-thread [streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-15574162-7649-4c98-acd2-7a68ced01d72-StreamThread-1] Informed to shut down
2019-09-01 14:54:17 INFO  StreamThread:207 - stream-thread [streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-15574162-7649-4c98-acd2-7a68ced01d72-StreamThread-1] State transition from PARTITIONS_REVOKED to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
2019-09-01 14:54:17 INFO  StreamThread:1178 - stream-thread [streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-15574162-7649-4c98-acd2-7a68ced01d72-StreamThread-1] Shutting down
2019-09-01 14:54:17 INFO  KafkaConsumer:1068 - [Consumer clientId=streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-15574162-7649-4c98-acd2-7a68ced01d72-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
2019-09-01 14:54:17 INFO  KafkaProducer:1153 - [Producer clientId=streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-15574162-7649-4c98-acd2-7a68ced01d72-StreamThread-1-producer] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
2019-09-01 14:54:17 INFO  StreamThread:207 - stream-thread [streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-15574162-7649-4c98-acd2-7a68ced01d72-StreamThread-1] State transition from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to DEAD
2019-09-01 14:54:17 INFO  StreamThread:1198 - stream-thread [streamingbean-test-20190901145412544-15574162-7649-4c98-acd2-7a68ced01d72-StreamThread-1] Shutdown complete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, I fixed this problem with a simple solution, but maybe not the most elegant. First I used a JSON String deserializer to get data from topic and then passed it to another deserializer that converts to my dynamic object.